# Add an element to an interface without increasing the complexity of the layout

Tags: layout, toggle, android

I need to implement a text and a switch to a login interface. This is what I made:

[image]

The problem is that I think it is a bit inappropriate, considering the layout and colors chosen in the interface. How would you improve it? Can it be a solution to close it inside a rectangular shape and move it to the center of screen?

Comment: Can you specify what the switch is for?

Comment: To enable a function (color palette) in the app. This is an app similar to Paint

Comment: Is this for a mobile app? Also does the switch any further action or UI element?

Comment: Yes, it is an app for tablets. The switch enable a function in the app, so it is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it can be confusing for a user to enable a setting from a screen which only contains login information.

Nevertheless if this is mandatory and within actual context, I would put it within the white card, between the password field and login button so there is a hierarchy of actions (1. enter pwd, 2. choose setting 3. login and move on).